# Who is this character wearing a green hood in "My Hero Academia" season 4?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the 1st opening of *My Hero Academia* season 4 titled *Polaris*, [at around 0:38](https://youtu.be/VtNgeDxYJzE?t=38), there's a character wearing a green hood on the right side.

[image: the character wearing a green hood]

They are also seen at the meeting and part of the Eri rescue mission.

Do they have a name?

Comment: It most likely is a filler character as it doesn't appear in the manga at any point.

Comment: @RigaCrypto well, apparently they appeared [in the manga (right-side, **spoiler warning!**)](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/bokunoheroacademia/images/4/46/Pro_Heroes_storm_the_Gunga_Mountain_Villa.png/revision/latest?cb=20200707184745) with caption "*Pro Heroes storm the Gunga Mountain Villa*", and based on the OP's scene, also looks like 1 of the (unidentified) Pro Heroes?

Comment: @AkiTanaka Omg, you have some good eyes. I could've swear they are anime only. Nice catch, but I don't remember the manga giving any names/superpowers to any of them.

Comment: The image made me think of [Beru Asui](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Beru_Asui) But I don't think she's been confirmed as a hero. There's also some visual differences.